# Hide mobile menu on click anywhere on a website

Tags: javascript, jquery, hamburger-menu

I have one problem, I want to hide the menu on click anywhere on the website, but nothing works for me :(
Here is my code for closing button:

```
$('.menu-toggle').on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if ( $('.lang-mobile').hasClass('is-open') ){
            $('.lang-mobile a').trigger('click')
        }
        if ( !$('header').hasClass('is-open')){
            $('header').addClass('is-open');
            $('#navbar-main').fadeIn();
        }
        else {
            $('header').removeClass('is-open');
            $('#navbar-main').fadeOut();
        }
```

Here is some of my HTML structure

```
<header class="header clear is-open" role="banner">

    <div class="navbar" id="navbar-main" style="display: block;">
<div class="navbar-container" style="height: 797px;">
<div class="navbar-item">
```

I've tried something like this

```
    $(document).click(function() {
    var container = $("#navbar-main");
    if (!container.is(event.target) && !container.has(event.target).length) {
        container.hide();
    }
});
```

and it's not working, could you please help me? What is incorrect here?

Comment: You need to accept `event` as an argument to the `click` handler function: `$(document).click(function(event) {...`

Comment: Thank you @RoryMcCrossan! But didn't help :(

Comment: @yousoumar OMG you are my savior! Yes, that is what I needed! Thank you very much! I added some needed parts to this code and it's working perfectly! Many-many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you [Youssouf Oumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15288641/yousoumar)
for sharing this link as an answer - [Mobile Menu - Click outside menu to close menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23333577/mobile-menu-click-outside-menu-to-close-menu) this the only thing that worked for me! I only added some needed parts to this code, so here you go if anyone noob like me and needs more details :D

```
$(document).mouseup(function(e){
   var header = $ (".header, .lang-mobile"); //I have two toggle menus with class that collapse navbars, I also have animation on toggle button that's why I need them also to work
   var menu = $(".navbar, .dropdown");//this is to hide menus 
   if (!menu.is(e.target) // The target of the click isn't the container.
   && menu.has(e.target).length === 0) // Nor a child element of the container
   {
      header.removeClass('is-open');
      menu.hide(); 
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This snippet handles two cases.

- Every time there's a click on the page it'll check if the header is open and close it
- Every time there's a click on the .menu-toggle item it'll open or close the header

```
<script>
    $(document).on('click', function() {
        var header = $(".header");
        if ( header.hasClass('is-open') ) {
            header.fadeOut();
            header.removeClass('is-open');
        }
    });

    $('.menu-toggle').on('click', function() {
        var header = $(".header");
        if ( !header.hasClass('is-open') ) {
            header.fadeIn();
            header.addClass('is-open');
        } else if ( header.hasClass('is-open') ) {
            header.fadeOut();
            header.removeClass('is-open');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hello @luke! Thank you for your help! But I think this part of the code is conflicting with my current which adds this class "is-open" by clicking on the toggle, and when I added this code, it just doesn't open the menu and trying to add is-open class and removes this fast
I also tried implement your code implement with mine and it open it but not closing, or it removes full header not just toggle menu, and removes it only by a clicking on a toggle, it's still not working when clicking outside the block :(